# Incorrect Autodiscovery URL when making use of EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am making use of the EWS managed API and it used to work perfectly until one fine day the autodiscover url changed (Is it possible?).

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@contoso.com", userData.Password);
service.AutodiscoverUrl("email@contoso.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

The url which I am getting is as follows: https://contoso.com/EWS.Exchange.asmx (note the EWS.Exchange).

I have enabled the tracing and that url is also in the traces but I got stuck.
Anyone has any ideas to why this is happening? I tried to search but found nothing.

Oh yes, the exchange which I am using is exchange 2007.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there is a misconfiguration somewhere. You might start by checking your EWS settings on the Client Access Server: `Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -Identity EWS(default web site)`

Comment: I got nothing on this so I decided to start from scratch and solved it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So, what I did was start from the beginning.
I removed my current certificates and created new ones... and it worked!

I do not understand why but hopefully it will help others as well :).

I followed this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/107415/it-how-to-create-a-self-signed-security-ssl-certificate-and-deploy-it-to-client-machines/